# Typing < in nano through Digital Ocean console

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, nano, digital-ocean

I am following a tutorial to setup php on Digitial Ocean and am using the web console.

I am trying to enter a "<" in a php file and all it types is ">"

I've also tried the same in a html and txt file with the same result, same issue with trying to paste in the "<".

Regards!

[image: Digitial Ocean Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Issue is due to a know bug in the QEMU software that Digital Ocean use to provide the console in the browser.

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2018-12/msg04631.html

A work around is to use ALT+60

Comment: A better workaround would be to connect to your server using SSH...

Comment: In general it would be better but its not available in all my use cases, that's why I needed a solution for the web console.